# How create Html button that run 2 linked js files?

Tags: javascript, html

What do I need to do in order to execute the code inside my two external JS files when the button shown below is clicked?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vending Machine</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="script2.js"></script>

        <button type="button" onclick="">Press the Button</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You call functions, you don't run files.

Comment: I don't think a novice should get negative points for asking simple questions. I will vote up

Comment: @j08691 Actually, if file will included to the document it will be called itself. So, just use function that will call `document.write("<script></script>")` onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your javascript file  there should be a function with name myFunction for example

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: I want when I click the button, html run the 2 script.js and scripts2.js files

Comment: Your javascript files may have inside many functions you must keep in mind that you can run only functions and not the actual files. So if you want onclick to make some actions you have to make a function doing what you want. 

For example make a new fuction like this
    function myFunction(){
    myFunction1();
    myFunction2();
     }

Answer (score 0):

You should call the 2 functions from the files inside your click

```
<button type="button" onclick="function1(); function2();">Press the Button</button>
```